# Getting an “Out of memory” Nginx error when attempting to run Lancache on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: raspberry-pi, nginx, raspbian, reverse-proxy, memory-error

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B and want to run [Lancache](https://github.com/RyanEwen/lan-cache-docker) on it. I know the performance will not be very good as the Raspberry Pi only has Fast Ethernet and a mobile CPU.

The Docker image consists of three parts: Dnsmasq, Sniproxy and Nginx.
The first two are working fine, but Nginx exits with an error:

```
[alert] 1#1: mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, 268435456) failed (12: Out of memory)
```

The pi uses ~100MB ram from 940MB, so there shouldn't be a problem.
There is also enough disk space free.

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the nginx configuration (`data/conf/*.nginx.conf`) in this project, you will find the following lines:

```
proxy_cache_path /cache/arenanet keys_zone=arenanet:256m levels=1:2:2 inactive=365d;
```

This will result in nginx allocating 256 MiB (268435456 bytes) of memory to manage this cache. This is what fails.

Now, there are 13 of these statements, one for each service supported. In total, this requires 3.25 GiB of memory. That may add up to more than the 32-bit address space can deliver, with or without swap. It simply cannot work.

You need to either modify this configuration, reducing the size of the key cache (and thus the maximum amount of cached objects), or use a 64-bit operating system (luckily, the Pi 3 has a 64-bit CPU). Still, without real RAM to back these caches, things will be extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try that I can think of is try increasing your swap space on your Raspberry Pi.

The swap file config is located at:

```
/etc/dphys-swapfile
```

The variable you're going to want to change is named "CONF_SWAPSIZE".  It should have a default value of 100, try increasing it to 2048 (2GB) to see if it fixes your issue.

Here's a little script I made for **increasing** the swap size:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/CONF_SWAPSIZE=.*/CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048/' /etc/dphys-swapfile
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

To set the swap size back to **normal**:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/CONF_SWAPSIZE=.*/CONF_SWAPSIZE=100/' /etc/dphys-swapfile
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

Note that increasing your swap size is a good way to wear out your SD card, so this may not be the best solution for the long run.

Comment: I've tried it and nothing changed. The maximum memory usage is ~100MB and the Sawp is never in use.